# EventArgs.Empty vs MouseEventArgs.Empty

Tags: c#, winforms

Got two methods.

```
control_SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
control_MouseClick(this, MouseEventArgs.Empty);
```

First one works fine, second one throws an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to
>   System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs

Casting `MouseMouseEventArgs.Empty` argument doesn't work either. How can i invoke the second method manually?

Comment: You should extract the code from the event handler into a separate method. Then call the method in both the Mouseclick event handler and at the certain point that you want to execute the code as well.

Comment: Hard to guess where you got MouseEventArgs.Empty from.  The point of the compile error is that you can never generate an event with junk event data.  A MouseClick is never "empty".  You always click at a specific location with a specific mouse button.

Comment: @Styxxy Mm yeah, actually that seems like the best approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the instance of MouseEventArgs to the method call. The static property MouseEventArgs.Empty returns an instance of type EventArgs (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

You need to instantiate new class using constructor:

```
control_MouseClick(this, new MouseEventArgs(...));
```

The parameters of constructor are defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no `MouseEventArgs.Empty` because there are properties that must be set. You'll need to instantiate the class so it can hold meaningful information (e.g. which button was pressed).

For example, if the handler cares about which button was pressed, you might do:

```
control_MouseClick(this, new MouseEventArgs { Button = MouseButtons.Left });
```